# Why does string.replace fail with char codes?

Tags: apex, pagereference

If have a login function that if there is a start URL I want it to go there other wise it should go to the default landing page. When I get the URL it substitutes special characters with char codes which don't work. If I substitute the actual character it works fine. Why does replace not work with char codes and how do I solve it

```
global PageReference login() {
  invalidPW = false;

  string loginURL = ApexPages.currentPage().getURL();
  system.debug(logginglevel.info, 'MEVION DEBUG: login URL from browser : ' + loginURL);
  if(loginURL.contains('startURL=') && loginURL.contains('mevCSPCaseDetail')) {        
    // loginURL = '/support/apex/mevCSPCaseDetail?cn=' + loginURL.right(8);
    loginURL = loginURL.substringAfter('startURL=');
    loginURL = loginURL.substringAfter('startURL=');
    loginURL.replace('%2F', '/');
    loginURL.replace('%3F', '?');
    loginURL.replace('%3D', '=');
  } else {
    loginURL = '/support/apex/mevCSPHome';
  }
  system.debug(logginglevel.info, 'MEVION DEBUG: login URL for Page Reference : ' + loginURL);
  PageReference t = Site.login(username,password,loginURL);
  if (t == null) { invalidPW = true; }

  return t;
}
```

This makes this debug line
MEVION DEBUG: login URL for Page Reference : %2Fsupport%2Fapex%2FmevCSPCaseDetail%3Fcn%3D00003609

I would've expected the %2F to get replaced with / 
the %3F to get replaced with a ?
and the %3D to get replaced with an =
If I just change the line so 
loginURL = /support/apex/mevCSPCaseDetail?cn=00003609
it works fine. The string replace function does not seem to work here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [EncodingUtil class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm) instead of replacing manually.

For example:

```
https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.salesforce.com%2Fdocs%2Fatlas.en-us.apexcode.meta%2Fapexcode%2Fapex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm
```

This string is automatically converted to below URL using `EncodingUtil.urlDecode(URL,'UTF-8');`

```
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm
```

---

**Solution**

```
String s2 = '%2Fsupport%2Fapex%2FmevCSPCaseDetail%3Fcn%3D00003609';
String s3 = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(s2,'UTF-8');
System.debug(s3);
```

This will give

```
/support/apex/mevCSPCaseDetail?cn=00003609
```

Comment: Thanks again salesforce-sas. You're awesome!